# What is meaning of 1/0 in PSExec command?

Tags: psexec

I am using **PSTools** to remotely running the application in Windows machine using the command

> PsExec.exe \Machine-i 1 -u Username -p Password -d /accepteula
>   C:\Test\PsexecConsole.exe

My question is what is the **1** means in the command?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation of the `PsExec.exe` application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) the `-i` switch is used to identify the session on the remote system:

> **`-i`** Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session.